# How to replace "if" block for large dataset to construct a new column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below dataframe:

[image: Data]

Now I want to construct a column "Status" which gives the status as failed if it is the last step(as shown in the "Final" column) and the TXN_STATUS is other than "SUCCESS".

The final output should be something like this:

[image: Output]

**I have data in millions and hence cannot use if..else statement**

Comment: Is this pandas or pyspark?

Comment: Which form a you store the data? Maybe they can be processed by a chunks?

Comment: Why is line 4 'Failed' if `TXN_STATUS` is "SUCCESS"?  What is the condition for 'Passed'?  Please update the question with all requirements.

Comment: @S3DEV: Sorry that was a typo error. Can you please have a look now. I have updated the question

Comment: @SarahMesser: This is pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Status'] = ((df['Final'] == "Last") & (df["TXN_STATUS"] == "SUCCESS"))\
                .groupby(df['TXN_ID']).transform('max').map({True:'Passed', False:'Failed'})
df
```

Output:

```
  TXN_STATUS    TXN_ID Final  Status
0    PENDING  21790353  Last  Failed
1    SUCCESS  21780356     0  Passed
2    SUCCESS  21780356  Last  Passed
3    SUCCESS  21790357     0  Failed
4     Failed  21790357  Last  Failed
5    PENDING  21790359     0  Passed
6    SUCCESS  21790359  Last  Passed
7    SUCCESS  21790366  Last  Passed
```

Details:

- First mark the records with 'Last' and 'SUCCESS' as True
- Then `groupby` 'TXN_ID' and take the `max` value which is True for all records in that group using `transform`
- Lastly, `map` all True values to 'Passed' and False to 'Failed'

This will make then entire TXN_ID 'Passed' if the Final is 'Last' and TXN_STATUS is 'SUCCESS'.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Pandas dataframe called `df`, this should work:

```
df['Status'] = 'Failed'
df.loc[(df['TXN_STATUS']=='SUCCESS') & (df['Final']=="Last"), 'Status'] = 'Passed'
```

Comment: Hi Sarah, it won't work since we have to update all the transactions having the same TXN_ID if the last step is successful. With this code, we are only updating the last step as Passed and it will not serve the purpose.

Comment: From your original description, I thought `df['Final']=="Last"` was a requirement for 'Passed'

Answer (score 0):

Because pandas internally uses broadcasting you can do the following:

```py
df['Status'] = 'Passed'  # create a new column called 'Status' 
                         # with values 'Passed' everywhere

df.loc[(df['TXN_STATUS'] == 'SUCCESS') & (df['Final'] == 'Last'), 'Status'] = 'Passed' 
# change the 'Status' to 'Failed' where the column 'Final' is 'Last' and 
# the column 'TXN_STATUS' is 'SUCCESS'
```

Another way would be to use `.apply()`:

```py
df['Status'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Failed' if x['Final'] == 'Last' and x['TXN_STATUS'] == 'SUCCESS' else 'Passed', axis=1)
```